# How many 10-bit words can be created with precisely four units (e.g., 1111000000)?

Tags: combinatorics

I think the answer is $$\frac{10!}{4!6!}.$$

This is because we can arrange $10$ objects in $10!$ ways, but then have to divide by $4!6!$ because the four $1$'s are identical and the six $0$'s are identical.

According to the website I got this problem from, I am incorrect:

https://www.hackmath.net/en/math-problem/41001?result=1

What is the verdict? Just so I can leave a comment for other users of the site.

Comment: You're right.  The web site you link to is wrong.  There are only $2^{10} = 1024$ 10-bit words so there's no way there can be $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 = 5040$ with precisely four units like the site says.

Comment: You are correct. The website counts all ones as distinguishable but they are not.

Comment: You are correct. It only matters how many ways you can place the 1's (or the 0's).  Once they are placed the position of the 0's (or the 1's) is forced. Finally, the symmetry of the situation leads to the answer you determined.

Comment: I had a look at the website to which you linked.  It did not take long for me to spot other errors.  The answer to the problem Word MATEMATIKA should be $94,500$, although the formula is correct.  The problem A license is formulated incorrectly and the answer is wrong.  Be wary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $$\frac{10!}{4!6!}.$$
This is because we can arrange 10
objects in 10!
ways, but then have to divide by 4!6!
because the four 1
's are identical and the six 0
's are identical.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).